# Loop duration of rec, av foundation framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I'm using the av foundation framework to record video. 
I've set a max duration of 10 sec for the video output.

Is it possible to loop the recording over the 10 sec interval instead of stop the recording.

My goal is to only store the 10 most recent sec of the video output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you wouldn't like to stop the record because you can never know when the user will eventually stop it, then your only option is to save the whole thing and trim it after the user clicked the stop button.

To trim a video, try using the [videoMaximumDuration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIVideoEditorController/videoMaximumDuration) of [UIVideoEditorController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

See an example of UIVideoEditorController here:
http://iphone-book-sample.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Chapter12/UIVideoEditorControllerSample/

Comment: Sooner or later, this will end-up the phone's memory. Isn't it possible to start over the recording without stop it? I'm thinking in the terms of "linked-lists", last slot refers to the first etc.

Comment: unfortunately i don't think it's possible because: 1. you have 1 camera resource available (front/back) 2. stopping and starting the video takes about a second (depends on how you're doing it).